# Can not RSYNC files from native NAS volume to mayQNAPcloud Storage

Tags: cloud, rsync, qnap

I would like to backup MariaDB in a container to myQNAPcloud Storage using RSYNC.
QNAP cloud resource mounted with QNAP HybridMount app.
I do this from the container using the command below.
$path - a variable containing the path to the mounted resource from myQNAPcloud storage.

```
rsync -ratxvO --force --delete -e '/usr/bin/ssh -p668 -x -q -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa' /backup admin@media:$path
```

RSYNC cannot change the modification time settings of directories and files in the mounted cloud resource.
So I added the "O" option, which bypasses the time modification. However, something is still wrong. The directory structure is created but no files are transferred.
The message is that RSYNC cannot change the temporary name of the transmitted file (starting with a dot) to the target name.
I would use RCLONE, which I use for backups to Google or M$ drives, and the problem would be solved. But there is no QNAP drive in the RCLONE menu.
So what should the RSYNC command look like to perform the above-mentioned backup?

At the moment, the disk mounted in this way certainly does not allow changing the modification time and has some problem with files whose names start with a dot.
Similarly, "normal" copying has problems with modification time:

```
    cp -a nc-data /share/external/.cm/0/1344d097f-4b77-483b-8d2f-34bcf4228353/
cp: preserving times for `/share/external/.cm/0/1344d097f-4b77-483b-8d2f-34bcf4228353/nc-data/data/maciek/files/Dokumenty/FIRMA/2016/2-luty/Dokumenty': Is a directory
cp: preserving times for `/share/external/.cm/0/1344d097f-4b77-483b-8d2f-34bcf4228353/nc-data/data/maciek/files/Dokumenty/FIRMA/2016/2-luty/Faktury': Is a directory
```

However, cp is not a good solution for larger numbers of files, only some of which are different in reality of rather slow speed access to cloud resources
Someone knows how to solve this problem?